# Копирование всех файлов из каталога (без самого каталога)

Tags: python

Всем привет! Есть задача: скопировать все файлы из одной папки и раскидать их по папкам пользователей. Использую этот скрипт. Но в нем надо задавать имена файлов. Можно ли как то прописать чтобы скрипт копировал ВСЕ файлы  из папки?

```
import shutil
shutil.copy('C:\\111.pdf','C:\\Папка1\\111.pdf')   # копировать
shutil.copy('C:\\111.pdf','C:\\Папка2\\111.pdf')
print ('готово!')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
import shutil

folder_from = 'C:\\Test_Files'
folder_to = 'C:\\Users_Files'
folder_user_list = ('User1', 'User2')

for f in os.listdir(folder_from):
    for folder_user in folder_user_list:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_from, f)):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(folder_from, f), os.path.join(folder_to, folder_user, f))
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_from, f)):
            shutil.copytree(os.path.join(folder_from, f), os.path.join(folder_to, folder_user, f))
```

Comment: спасибо! скрипт будет копировать только файлы из папки1 в папку2? или просто копировать папку? нужен первый вариант

Comment: @dimahimma только файлы

Comment: скрипт работает, но при попытке скопировать не только вложенные файлы, но и вложенные папки- выдает ошибку Permission denied. и указывает на вложенную папку, которую нужно скопировать

Comment: @dimahimma подправил ответ

Comment: читал про shutil на каком то сайте, про copytree вообще ни слова было( сейчас попробую

Comment: да работает как часы) а так я пробовал copy и copy2

Comment: еще вопрос: попробовал для сетевых папок- не работает, либо возникает ошибка No such file or directory, либо ошибки не возникает, но ничего не копируется (путь сетевой типа \\server\user1

Comment: @dimahimma путь правильно прописан? `\\\\server\\user1`

Comment: да экранировал все слеши кроме первой пары, как то не думал что можно ставить по 4 штуки) все работает

Comment: @dimahimma: если вы хотите скопировать как сами **файлы** в папке, так и вложенные в ней **подпапки**, то обновите ваш вопрос и явно это упомяните.

Comment: можете пояснить действие for f и for folder_user? эти переменные же не обьявлялись

Comment: @dimahimma `f` перебирает все названия папок и файлов из `os.listdir()`, `folder_user` перебирает список папок пользователей `('User1', 'User2')`, куда нужно будет скопировать файлы

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибаюсь - немного переделала Ваш ответ под винду, текст: import shutil from pathlib import Path for dest_dir in Path(r"D:\python\code\456").iterdir(): if dest_dir.is_dir(): for path in Path(r"D:\python\code\123").iterdir(): if path.is_dir(): shutil.copytree(str(path), str(dest_dir / path.name), copy_function=shutil.copy) # use the same copy function else: shutil.copy(str(path), str(dest_dir)) смысл - рекурсивно всё включая каталоги и подкаталоги из "D:\python\code\123" скопировать в "D:\python\code\456". Ошибок не выдает, но в первый же цикл не заходит.

Comment: @Юлия папка `D:\python\code\456` существует? она не пустая? для чего перебирать вложенные в нее папки?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы скопировать все pdf-файлы из `/source-dir` директории в папки Books из домашних директорий пользователей в bash, можно воспользоваться [ответом @Robert Gamble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/195972/4279):

```bsh
$ echo /home/*/Books | xargs -rn1 cp /source-dir/*.pdf
```

На Питоне:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

for dest_dir in Path('/home').glob('*/Books'):
    if dest_dir.is_dir():
        for path in Path('/source-dir').glob('*.pdf'):
            shutil.copy(str(path), str(dest_dir))
```

Если все файлы (включая "cкрытые":  `.*`) нужно скопировать, то внутренний цикл можно записать как:

```
        for path in Path('/source-dir').iterdir():
            if path.is_file():
                shutil.copy(str(path), str(dest_dir))
```

---

Если кроме файлов, вы хотите скопировать и вложенные директории рекурсивно -- аналог:

```bsh
$ echo /home/*/Books | xargs -rn1 cp -R /source-dir/*
```

На Питоне:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

for dest_dir in Path('/home').glob('*/Books'):
    if dest_dir.is_dir():
        for path in Path('/source-dir').iterdir():
            if path.is_dir():
                shutil.copytree(str(path), str(dest_dir / path.name),
                                copy_function=shutil.copy) # use the same copy function
            else:
                shutil.copy(str(path), str(dest_dir))
```

Comment: проблема в том, что файлы могут быть абсолютно любыми: сегодня надо раскидать .pdf завтра .doc итд

Comment: прописывать все расширения через запятую не выход(

Comment: @dimahimma: обновил ответ, чтобы он все файлы и директории рекурсивно бы копировал.

Answer (score 1):

Только учусь питону и вот так делал подобное, знаю что решение не наилучшее, но как смог..
Это типа для сортировки

```
import shutil
import os
files_list=os.listdir('C:/test/')
i=0
for lin in files_list:
    files_list[i]='C:/test/'+lin
    i+=1
i=0
for n in files_list:
    a=os.path.splitext(files_list[i])
    print(a)

    if   a[1] == '.txt':
        shutil.move(files_list[i], 'C:/test/doc/')
    elif a[1] == '.doc':
        shutil.move(files_list[i], 'C:/test/doc/')
    elif a[1] == '.pdf':
        shutil.move(files_list[i], 'C:/test/doc/')
    elif a[1] == '.pptx':
        shutil.move(files_list[i], 'C:/test/doc/')
    elif a[1] == '.docx':
        shutil.move(files_list[i], 'C:/test/doc/')
    elif a[1] == '.png':
        shutil.move(files_list[i], 'C:/test/img/')
    elif a[1] == '.jpg':
        shutil.move(files_list[i], 'C:/test/img/')
    elif a[1] == '.jpeg':
        shutil.move(files_list[i], 'C:/test/img/')
    elif a[1] == '.bmp':
        shutil.move(files_list[i], 'C:/test/img/')
    i+=1
```

Comment: Это лучше реализовать словарем.

Comment: можно показать на примере?

Comment: Что-то вроде этого: https://repl.it/GiPq/0